# Modifying Google Drive File List Request parameters in C++

Tags: c++, google-drive-api, http-request-parameters

I find myself writing code in C++ to integrate Google Drive with a desktop app, and I need to modify the `q` parameter of a File List Request. Is there a way to do this with the Drive API and functions like `List(), Fetch()`, etc? Or will I have to bite the bullet and make the request directly via GET or POST?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a C++ client at the moment, you need implement a REST client by yourself.